# Building survey from railscast in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I have been following both the old and revised [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true) & [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?autoplay=true) for something that i have to make along the same lines

I followed it upto some point but neither are the questions being displayed on the form nor are the answers getting added . Following is my model code

**answers.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :content, :question_id
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**surveys.rb**

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
   attr_accessor :name, :questions_attributes
   has_many :questions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**questions.rb**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :content, :survey_id, :answers_attributes
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Surveys Controller**

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /surveys
  # GET /surveys.json
  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  # GET /surveys/1
  # GET /surveys/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    3.times do
      question = @survey.questions.build
      4.times { question.answers.build }
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_survey
      @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :question_id)
    end
end
```

**Views**

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'question_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Question", f, :questions %>
```

**_question_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Question" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'answer_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Answer", f, :answers %>
</fieldset>
```

**_answers_fields.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Answer" %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove" %>
</p>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @survey.name %>
</p>

<ol>
  <% for question in @survey.questions %>
  <li><%= h question.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_survey_path(@survey) %> |
  <%= link_to "Destroy", @survey, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %> |
  <%= link_to "View All", surveys_path %>
</p>
```

**Migrations**

```
class CreateSurveys < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :surveys do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :survey_id
      t.string :integer
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is there anything else i am missing out that needs to be done in rails 5 , i have been hours at this and it still confuses me why does it show me this **error - Table 'app.answers' doesn't exist** when i am calling answers from nested form . Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated .

Comment: The main issue arises in new method of survey controller , this particular line - 4.times { question.answers.build }

Comment: Yes , i just have two migrations of survey and questions

Comment: Updated the same

Comment: Did you end up having a solution that worked well? I'm currently having the exact problem that you're experiencing and I'm wondering if your project is open source. Going to see if the answer below solves most of the issues, but this has been a multi-day frustration, since I have to build a quiz for a client, and it's way more complicated than I originally expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is it looks like you forgot an 'answer' migration to create the tables, create that and run it and should fix things up.

Additionally, those `attr_accessor` calls are going to be messing things up. They were required in older versions of Rails, but aren't anymore and now just serve throw things off. Example

With `attr_accessor` code

```
post = Post.new(title: "Something")
#=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
post.title = "Something"
#=> "Something"
puts post
#=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Without

```
post = Post.new(title: "Something")
#=> #<Post id: nil, title: "Something", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
post.title = "Something Else"
#=> "Something Else"
puts post
#=> #<Post id: nil, title: "Something Else", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As you can see, the first block, where my Post model had the `attr_accessor` for the `title` attribute, nothing was working as expected; I couldn't update the title. Once I removed it, things started to work as they should.

Based on the chat discussion, your `_form.html.erb` is missing `form_for` tag, and should looks something like

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br /> 
  <%= f.text_field :name %> 
  <!-- your current code here -->
<% end %>
```

you've got `_answers_field.html.erb` and in `_question_fields.html.erb` are calling

```
<%= render 'answer_fields', f: builder %>
```

Notice, the plural/singular mismatch.

and lastly, in your controller, you aren't permitting the nested attribute params which should end up looking like (unless I'm mistaken)

```
def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :question_attributes: [:id, :content, :_destroy, answer_attributes: [:id, :content, :_destroy])
end
```

Last couple of issues from chat were that the associations needed `inverse_of` because `belongs_to` is required by default in rails 5. And the last minor thing is that Answer is currently inheriting ActiveRecord::Base and the other models ApplicationRecord

Comment: Even if i do comment out the attr_accessor , it's showing the same issue . Updated the view code .

Comment: Also reading up a bit on inverse_of is needed if you are a newbie to rails 5 like me . More on it here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html